# JavaFX Mediaplayer.setOnPlaying() Thread not updating

Tags: multithreading, javafx, media-player

I am attempting to create a simple media player in JavaFX. I am having difficulty, however, updating a thread initiated when the media is first played.

```
mediaPlayer.setOnPlaying(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    //status and timeStatus are both Labels with default text()
    //mediaLocation is a default string created from a File object
    status.setText("Playing: " + mediaLocation);
    timeStatus.setText("Time: " + mediaPlayer.getCurrentTime());
  }
});
```

When I run this, timeStatus remains at "0.0 ms" for the song's duration. Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html

Information about playback position, rate, and buffering may be obtained from the currentTime, currentRate, and bufferProgressTime properties, respectively. Media marker notifications are received by an event handler registered as the onMarker property.

The onPlaying property gets called once, when the state changes to PLAYING, meaning play()  was invoked.

Comment: However, since the onPlaying property gets called once, and it initiates the thread, shouldn't the thread continue updating until the mediaplayer is stopped? Thus continually resetting the text of the timeStatus label?